# IllegalStateException after upgrading web app to Spring Boot 2.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, servlets, contextpath

My web app is no longer starting after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.4.  It is throwing the following error :

```
Unable to locate the default servlet for serving static content. Please set the 'defaultServletName' property explicitly.
```

I am using the following code to change the context path and my research points me to that being the "culprit" (changing context path) :

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() 
{
    String tomcatPort = environment.getProperty("tomcatPort");
    
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    tomcat.setPort(tomcatPort != null ? Integer.parseInt(tomcatPort) : 8080);
    tomcat.setContextPath("/Carbon");
    tomcat.setBaseDirectory(new File(System.getenv("MDHIS3_HOME")));
    
    setTomcatProtocol(tomcat);
    
    return tomcat;
}
```

I have the following method and I can see that it can be used to pass a defaultServletName but I have no idea what value I'm supposed to pass :

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) 
{
    configurer.enable();
}
```

This worked perfectly on Spring Boot 2.3.4.  What value do I pass in there?  Is it the name of the main controller?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As [described in the Spring Boot 2.4 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#default-servlet-registration), the `DefaultServlet` provided by the embedded Servlet container is no longer registered by default. If your application needs it, as yours appears to do, you can enable it by setting `server.servlet.register-default-servlet` to `true`.

Alternatively, you can configure it programatically using a `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` bean:

```java
@Bean
WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> enableDefaultServlet() {
    return (factory) -> factory.setRegisterDefaultServlet(true);
}
```

Note that the configuration must be applied via a customizer so that the default properties-based configuration does not overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you Andy, thought I read all the relevant stuff in there yesterday night but I guess it was late.  This does indeed fix it but is there a way for this to be done programmatically somehow?  Trying to cut down on the number of properties in my application.properties file.  Thanks!

Comment: There's a setter on `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` that you can use. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The programmatic method doesn't work, I can only get past this error with the property

Comment: Ah, yes. That's an ordering problem that causes the configuration to be overridden. I've updated the answer with a better approach.

Comment: Yep that worked!  Thanks Andy, you guys are awesome!  Thanks for a great product!